# How can I make my encoded data only 5 characters?

Tags: php, encoding

Currently, I am messing with a project which is using Base64 Encoding on the front end through a URL hook `?id=someencodeddatahere` I know this is probably quite messy but regardless it's working pretty well for me.

This is being used for external websites to just toss some data and have it decoded on the actual page, is there any way that I can limit the encoded data to only 5 characters displaying in the slug appose to the entire encoded string but still generating the same output, without storing data in a database?

Comment: Can you show some code please?